# Error on using RegExp : Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find words and bold them.

Here is my script code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".s-text").each(function(){
        var search = "apple";
        var str = $(this).html();
        var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
        var result = str.replace(regex, "<b><font color='blue'>" + search + "</font></b>");
        $(this).html() = result;
    });
});
```

And on my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 s-text">
    <h4 class="font-medium m-b-0">something text</h4>
</div>
```

When I execute, I get Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a method, but you are assigning values to it as if it is a *property*.

Change

```
$(this).html() = result;
```

To

```
$(this).html(result);
```

Comment: Wow Thanks! Worked!